# Can you build a treehouse (or tree deck/platform) in a floodplain without an HH study?

Tags: flooding, permitting, treehouse

While I was aware that part of my land was in a floodplain, turns out that in 2014 the DNR (or FEMA or something) declared the entire 5.5 acre parcel is in a floodplain. In order for zoning to approve a permit, they need a Hydraulic and Hydrologic Study to determine what is floodway and floodfringe. This study would cost about $10,000 and all I want to do is build a couple platforms in the trees so we can pitch tents on them and camp in the summer.

Does anyone know another way to determine Base Flood Elevation that might allow zoning to approve a permit without such an expensive study? The platforms would be completely fixed in the trees without any ground support, plumbing, or electrical.

The property is in Wisconsin on the Chippewa River.

Comment: I would consider those temporary and not permanent structures.  Maybe that is a reasonable 'out'.

Comment: I don't know (my similar property is on a non-navigable waterway, so that's a bit different). However, since you won't be modifying the waterway itself I'd probably take an ask forgiveness rather than permission approach, considering that anything you do can be completely reversed.

Comment: I agree with Steve Wellens that this probably isn't a regulated situation anyway. It's a treehouse.

Comment: The base flood elevation numbers provided by FEMA are usually considered gospel.  That's why jurisdictions and insurance companies use them for assessing flood risk and insurance premiums.  If there's a obvious mistake, you can go through a process to have that changed.

Comment: One of the things that's happened is that the old flood maps based on historic river levels and flood events are not considered valid in today's climate.  There are towns around me that have had half dozen or so 100 year floods in the last 20 years, and two 1,000 year floods in 2 years.

Comment: All that said, I would just go ahead and build it.  The worst that would (probably) happen is that you would have to take it down, and you could probably draw that process out for years.

Comment: @SteveSh Thank you — yeah, I've been really confused because if it's up in a tree, how do the flood rules even apply? I just need to make sure it's higher than the worst-case predicted flood levels.

Comment: @aleks1217 - I'm no expert, but I think that the flood zones/levels only come into play if you're going to 1) have a mortgage on or 2) have insurance on a structure that's in a flood zone.  If you're willing to assume the risk of not having insurance, then you can do pretty much anything you want, subject to whatever other zoning codes or restrictions are in place.  An awful lot of this is jurisdiction dependent.

Comment: @SteveSh Most building codes, I would think, are going to have a standard height above Base Flood Elevation (BFE).  In Florida, where I live, the state building code specifies that the lowest horizontal structural member must be 12 inches above BFE.  My local jurisdiction (bless their hearts) ups the anti and makes us build 18 inches above lowest adjacent road crown, even in you're in a zone x area.  So to get a pre-fab shed placed, I'm going to have to bring in almost 2 feet of fill. . . for my push mower and shovels and rakes.

Comment: these laws are to keep you from building a structure that makes floods worse for ther people, not to protect your property.  But I mean a treehouse?

Comment: @Edwin: Or put it on pilings
 Which would both be less likely to have erosion problems and leave more surface area that can soak up rain and thus help delay flooding.

Answer (score -1):

### Docks are *designed* to be in water

The difference between a deck and a dock is a bunch of empty drums underneath the dock.  (plastic ones preferably).

Obviously, if you're building a dock, you don't need to spend $10,000 to prove the land it's on won't flood :)

If you want to build a dock up in a tree, that's your business :)

Comment: I'm sure you were being a bit facetious, but not all docks are built on top of empty drums.  Mine is built on 12" pilings driven into the river bed.  Just like a deck, only stronger.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that a building inspector would go for this.